# How to send Data over Bluetooth Module HC-05 using Arduino?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno

```
    /*
 == MASTER CODE ==
*/
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11); // RX | TX
#define ledPin 9
int state = 0;
int Vry = 0;
int Vrx = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
 BTSerial.begin(38400); // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
}
void loop() {
if(BTSerial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port
 state = BTSerial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port
}
// Controlling the LED
/*if (state == '1') {
 digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // LED ON
 state = 0;
}
else if (state == '0') {
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // LED ON
 state = 0;
}

*/
// Reading the potentiometer
//Vry = analogRead(A0);
/*
Vrx = analogRead(A1);
int VrxMapped = map(Vrx, 0, 1023, 0, 255); 

//int Vry_mapped = map(Vrx, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
//int Vrx_mapped = map(Vry, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
Serial.print("Vrx");
Serial.println(VrxMapped);
//Serial.print("Vry");
//Serial.println(Vry);

*/
Vrx = analogRead(A1);
BTSerial.write(Vrx);
Serial.print("Vrx: ");
Serial.println(Vrx);

//BTSerial.write(Vry);
delay(2000);
}
```

and the slave code is as follows,

```
/*
 == SLAVE CODE ==
*/
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define button 8
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(5, 3); // RX | TX
// connect motor controller pins to Arduino digital pins
// motor one
int enA = 10;
int in1 = 9;
int in2 = 8;
int enB = 11;
int in3 = 7;
int in4 = 6;
int jx = A0;
int jy = A1;
int mx = 0; //right motor
int my = 0; //left motor

int state = 0;
int  i = 0;
int buttonState = 0;
int ledPin = 13;
void setup() {
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
 BTSerial.begin(38400); // HC-05 default speed
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(button, INPUT);
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  //my = analogRead(BTSerial.read());

 // mx = analogRead(BTSerial.read());
if(BTSerial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port
  int state = BTSerial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port

  //Serial.print('y');
  //Serial.println(my+100,DEC);
  Serial.print('x');
  Serial.println(state);

}  
if  (i == 2){
  i=0;
}
  /*int mapx = map(mx,0,1023,0,255);
  int mapy = map(my,0,1023,0,255);
  if (mapx>127)
  {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(enA,mapx); 
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    analogWrite(enA,127-mapx); 
  }
  if (mapy>127)
  {
    digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
    analogWrite(enB,mapy);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
    analogWrite(enB,127-mapy); 
  }
  delay(1000);
*/
 /*Serial.println(state);
if(BTSerial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port
 state = BTSerial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port

}

if (state > 120){
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   // sets the LED on
  delay(1000);                  // waits for a second
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    // sets the LED off
  delay(1000);
}
else{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   // sets the LED on
  delay(1000);                  // waits for a second

}
// Controlling the servo motor

// Reading the button
buttonState = digitalRead(button);
if (buttonState == HIGH) {
 BTSerial.write('1'); // Sends '1' to the master to turn on LED
}
else {
 BTSerial.write('0');
}
*/
delay(2000);
}
```

The problem here is following,
if I send 1 from master I get 130 at slave end, I have no idea how Serial communication works and how data can be received over bluetooth devices!

Answer (score 0):

The serial of bluetooth in read function returns character.